# Python interval based sparse container

Tags: python, data-structures, numpy, nlp, nltk

I am trying to create an interface between structured data and `NLTK`. `NLP` libraries generally work with bags of words, hence I need to turn my structured data into bags of words.

I need to associate the offset of a word with it's meta-data.Therefore my best bet is to have some sort of container that holds ranges as keys (allowing nested ranges) and can retrieve all the meta-data (multiple if the word offset is part of a nested range).

What code can I pickup that would do this efficiently (--i.e., sparse represention of the data ) ? Efficient because my global corpus will have at least a few hundred megabytes.

Note :

- I am serialising structured forum posts. which will include posts with sections of quotes with them. I want to know which topic a word belonged to, and weather it's a quote or user-text. There will probably be additional metadata as my work progresses. Note that a word belonging to a quote is what I meant by nested meta-data, so the word is part of a quote, that belongs to a post made by a user.
- I know that one can tag words in `NLTK` I haven't looked into it, if its possible to do what I want that way please comment. But I am still looking for the original approach.
- There is probably something in `numpy` that can solve my problem, looking at that now

**edit**

The input data is far too complex to rip out and post. I have found what I was looking for tho http://packages.python.org/PyICL/. I needed to talk about intervals and not ranges :D I have used boost extensively, however making that a dependency makes me a bit uneasy (Sadly, I am having compiler errors with PyICL :( ).

**The question now is:** anyone know an interval container library or data structure that can be used to index nested intervals in a sparse fashion. Or put differently provides similar semantics to boost.icl

Comment: Try posting a sample of input data and the output data structures you want--then maybe someone can help you connect the dots. The question is a touch vague in its current state.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `PyICL` or `boost.icl` Instead of relying on a specialized library you could just use sqlite3 to do the job ? If you use an in0memory version it will still be a few orders of magnitudes slower than `boost.icl` (from experience coding other data structures vs sqlite3) but should be more effective than using a c++ `std::vector` style approach on top of python containers.

You can use two integers and have `date_type_low < offset < date_type_high` predicate in your where clause. And depending on your table structure this will return nested/overlapping ranges.